# Retaining Variable Names through Custom Functions

Tags: r

I'm working with several data frames and I want to create a function that quickly divides any two columns from a data frame and names a new column in that data frame.

My code thus far:

```
    relate.ratio = function(x, y, z) {
        q = as.data.frame(y/z)
        x <<- cbind2(x, q)
    }
```

My problem is that the result retains x, y, and z as the names instead of what I actually used as my argument. Possibly because of the global assign? But I couldn't see an alternative without the global assign.

An example:

```
    relate.ratio(Data, Data$1, Data$2)
```

Will give as a result a data frame named x and new column name of y/z. All the numbers are correct but the names have me tripped up. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe don't reinvent the wheel, just use `transform()`? Although it depends a little on how you intend to use it. If you want something less focused on interactive use, I'd be passing character representations of the column names. Either way, the function should return and reassign the modified df, don't bother with `<<-`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rename the column in your custom function:

```
relate.ratio = function(x, y, z) {
 q = as.data.frame(y/z)
 colnames(q) = "test"
 x <<- cbind2(x, q)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
    relate.ratio = function(x, y, z) {
      q = as.data.frame(y/z)
      x <<- cbind2(x, q)
      names(x) <<- c(deparse(substitute(x)),paste0(deparse(substitute(y)),'/',deparse(substitute(z))))
    }

a <- 1:10
b <- 10:19
c <- 20:29
relate.ratio(a,b,c)
x
```